# JWT - per user signing key

Tags: redis, jwt

In my project there's a requirement to invalidate all jwt tokens of a user when the user changes his password. I was thinking of giving each user a different signing key, and simply reset the key when password is changed. Then I googled around and found Redis is a good place to store those per-user keys. Everything seems to work just fine.

But there one thing I cannot get my head around. Since it has to hit Redis once per request, is it any different than issuing the user an opaque token instead of JWT, and store the token -> JWT payload mapping in Redis?Isn't that defeats the purpose of using JWT?

Answer (score 1):

To invalidate tokens you need to revoke them. OAuth spec also does not require getting secret key from remote server every time you need to validate JWT (as you said it kind of defeats the purpose). The key can be stored locally at resource site. 
You have two options here:

1) Introspect the JWT token from resource side against OAuth server every time it validates it. Seems like overkill to me. The best approach is to give short expiration time to JWT token and let the already issued tokens to just expire.

2) Have the resource store the secret key locally and when it fails to validate go and get the key and re-validate it again.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of invalidating the token, there's no particular need to store the JWT in Redis - anything that you can check and later invalidate should do the trick.

That said, presumably you're using a JWT for other reasons.  For example, it's what the AuthN/Identity service provides.  Or perhaps you use it to store claims or other metadata that you validate as part of the AuthN/AuthZ logic.  In that case, since it's handy, storing the JWT seems very reasonable.